# Setting the alpha value (transparency) of legend to match alpha in plot in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I've seen this question asked before but there appears to be no solution so am just wondering if it is at all possible.

I have a bar plot in MatLab and have set the transparency:

```
B = bar(x,y,'stacked');
set(B(1),'facecolor',[0 0.3906 0]) 
set(B(2),'facecolor',[0.5625 0.9297 0.5625])
ch1 = get(B(1),'child');
set(ch1,'facea',.5)
ch2 = get(B(2),'child');
set(ch2,'facea',.5)
```

And I would like the transparency in the plot to be reflected in the legend:

```
BL = legend ((B([1 2])),{'data1','data2'},'fontsize',10);
```

However, it appears the alpha value in the legend is 1.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `PatchInLegend = findobj(BL, 'type', 'patch');` to find the patch objects in your legend. You can then set their transparency using `set(PatchInLegend, 'facea', 0.5)` to set their transparency.

**Before Transparent**

[image]

**After Transparent**

[image]

So the colour changes, and it does look a lot better.

Answer (score 12):

Note with the 2014b update a slight change is needed. The information about patches etc. seems now to be held in the "icons" output from the legend command, so you need;

```
[BL,BLicons] = legend ((B([1 2])),{'data1','data2'},'fontsize',10);
```

and then

```
PatchInLegend = findobj(BLicons, 'type', 'patch');
set(PatchInLegend, 'facea', 0.5)
```

for this to work now. Just spent an hour figuring this out, so thought I'd pass it on:)

Comment: Can you reproduce these results in MATLAB 2016b? - - I cannot at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't code golf and the question is a bit old, but I do have an approach that is the same result in fewer lines (found it [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/transparent-legend)) where you directly modify the `BoxFace` property instead of having to search through properties as in the two currently accepted answers.

```
lgnd = legend(legendTextCells);
set(lgnd.BoxFace, 'ColorType', 'truecoloralpha', 'ColorData', uint8([255;255;255;0.5*255]));
```

where `legendTextCells` is your cell array of legend text, and the alpha value can be set by modifying the decimal coefficient in `0.5*255`.

Comment: Life is Code Golf. Joke. Life is not Code Golf, but Code Travelling Salesman Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in the 2018b version `legend` takes automatically care of the transparency issue. This means you do not have to do any additional manipulation to get transparency of the legend to match transparency in the plot.